# Trying to retrieve data from another firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve data from another firebase database but I get nothing to show. I don't get any errors and my app doesn't crash which is a good thing, but it doesn't show any data and there is data in the database.

Can someone please help me resolve this issue?

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
myUploads = new ArrayList<Model_Information>();
aAdapter = new Adapter1(getContext(), myUploads);
recyclerView.setAdapter(aAdapter);
aAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://boot0-43081.firebaseio.com/").getReference("Posts");

if (InternetConnection.checkConnection(getContext())) {
    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                for (DataSnapshot postsnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Model_Information upload=postsnapshot.getValue(Model_Information.class);

                    myUploads.add(upload);
           
                    recyclerView.invalidate();
                }
                linearLayoutWithoutItems.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

             aAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }else{
                linearLayoutWithoutItems.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }
```

Json

```
{
  "Posts" : {
    "37trzrENv0WGEgHWTPvKZ08wWcY2" : {
      "-MT1gIzSVIG4cF_ipquI" : {
        "created" : "2-09-2021",
        "headline" : "Danny Dinner",
        "id" : "-MT1gIzSVIG4cF_ipquI",
        "mImageUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/boot0-43081.appspot.com/o/37trzrENv0WGEgHWTPvKZ08wWcY2%2F1612805391640.jpg?alt=media&token=9e819b43-507d-4c07-91cb-c006e16a8def",
        "main_id" : "-MT1gIzSVIG4cF_ipquI",
        "time" : "1:29 AM",
        "timestamp" : 1612805393601,
        "views" : 0,
        "websiteurl" : "www.danny.com"
      }
    }
  },
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the JSON under `Posts` (as text, no screenshots please)? You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I just edited my question and added the json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of it your `Posts` node has a key with the UID of a user under it, and then under there is a list of the posts for that user.

Since your code reads the entire `Posts` node, it need to handle both level of nesting here: users and posts. So you need two nested loops:

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://boot0-43081.firebaseio.com/").getReference("Posts");

if (InternetConnection.checkConnection(getContext())) {
    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    for (DataSnapshot postsnapshot : userSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Model_Information upload=postsnapshot.getValue(Model_Information.class);

                        myUploads.add(upload);           
                        recyclerView.invalidate();
                    }
                }
                linearLayoutWithoutItems.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

             aAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }else{
                linearLayoutWithoutItems.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
```

Or if you only want to read the posts for the current user, that'd be:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://boot0-43081.firebaseio.com/")
    .getReference("Posts").child(uid);
```

And then you can leave the `onDataChange` unmodified.